# Marking specific tiles in geom_tile() / geom_raster()

Tags: r, ggplot2

Let's say I have a data.frame like this:

```
molten <- data.frame(
  Var1 = factor(
    rep(c("A", "B", "C", "D"), 5),
    levels = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J")
  ),
  Var2 = rep(6:10, each = 4L),
  value = c(
    -0.468920099229389, 0.996105987531978, -0.527496444770932, -0.767851702991822,
    -0.36077954422072, -0.145335912847538, 0.114951323188032, 0.644232124274217,
    0.971443502096584, 0.774515290180507, -0.436252398260595, -0.111174676975868,
    1.16095688943808, 0.44677656465583, -0.708779168274131, 0.460296447139761,
    -0.475304748445917, -0.481548436194392, -1.66560630161765, -2.06055347675196
  ),
  na = rep(c(FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE), c(8L, 1L, 7L, 1L, 3L)),
  row.names = c(
    51L, 52L, 53L, 54L, 61L, 62L, 63L, 64L, 71L, 72L, 73L, 74L,
    81L, 82L, 83L, 84L, 91L, 92L, 93L, 94L
  )
)

head(molten)

  Var1 Var2      value    na
1    A    1 -0.2413015 FALSE
2    B    1  1.5077282 FALSE
3    C    1 -1.0798806 TRUE
4    D    1  2.0723791 FALSE
```

Now, I want to plot a tile (or raster)  plot using ggplot and *mark* those tiles which have `na=TRUE`. Currently I plot the marks as points:

```
g <- ggplot( molten ) +
  geom_raster( aes( x = Var1, y = Var2, fill = value )  ) + 
  scale_fill_gradient2( low = "blue", high = "red", na.value="black", name = "" ) +
  geom_point( aes( x = Var1, y = Var2, size= as.numeric(na) ) )
```

[image: tiles with points]

However, I don't like this plot very much for two reasons:

1. There is still a point drawn even if `molten$na = FALSE`. Sure I could specify `data=molten[ molten$na, ]`, but actually this should be possible without specifying another data set.
2. I don't like the points, but would rather like to have frames around or stripes through the tiles. But I have no idea how to achieve this. If I would use `geom_segment()` for stripes, how would I specify `yend`and `xend`?

Comment: "but actually this should be possible without specifying another data set" Why? Specifying separate data sets for different layers is a huge feature of ggplot, and is precisely how one is supposed to do what you want (for (1) at least).

Comment: How about `size = ifelse(na, 1, NA)` instead of `size = as.numeric(na)`?

Comment: @bdemarest because it simply doesn't work: `geom_point( aes( x = Var1, y = Var2, size = ifelse( na, 1, NA ) ) )` gives me a point in each tile.

Comment: @joran if you say that this is how it is supposed to work thats fine, I was just expecting to get it work without subsetting and thought I have missed something.

Comment: @Beasterfield: Sorry! I didn't test it. I would be happy to try a few other things if you could make your example reproducible. Maybe you could give us the output of `dput(subset(molten, Var2 > 5 & Var1 %in% c("A", "B", "C", "D")))`?

Comment: @bdemarest I thoght my example was without `dput`reproducible. Anyways, see my edit.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Here are two possible approaches:

In Example 1, I used `ifelse` and `scale_size_manual` to control whether a point is plotted in each cell.

In Example 2, I created a small auxiliary data.frame and used `geom_rect` to plot a rectangle instead of a dot. For convenience, I converted Var2 to factor. In ggplot2, each step along a discrete/factor axis is length 1.0. This allows easy computation of the values for `geom_rect`.

```
# Using ggplot2 version 0.9.2.1
library(ggplot2)

# Test dataset from original post has been assigned to 'molten'.

molten$Var2 = factor(molten$Var2)

# Example 1.
p1 = ggplot(data=molten, aes(x=Var1, y=Var2, fill=value)) +
     geom_raster() +
     scale_fill_gradient2(low="blue", high="red", na.value="black", name="") +
     geom_point(aes(size=ifelse(na, "dot", "no_dot"))) +
     scale_size_manual(values=c(dot=6, no_dot=NA), guide="none") +
     labs(title="Example 1")

ggsave(plot=p1, filename="plot_1.png", height=3, width=3.5)
```

[image]

```
# Example 2.
# Create auxiliary data.frame.
frames = molten[molten$na, c("Var1", "Var2")]
frames$Var1 = as.integer(frames$Var1)
frames$Var2 = as.integer(frames$Var2)

p2 = ggplot(data=molten) +
     geom_raster(aes(x=Var1, y=Var2, fill=value)) +
     scale_fill_gradient2(low="blue", high="red", na.value="black", name="") +
     geom_rect(data=frames, size=1, fill=NA, colour="black",
       aes(xmin=Var1 - 0.5, xmax=Var1 + 0.5, ymin=Var2 - 0.5, ymax=Var2 + 0.5)) +
     labs(title="Example 2")

ggsave(plot=p2, filename="plot_2.png", height=3, width=3.5)
```

[image]

Comment: The second answer is what I was actually looking for and which should work with `geom_segement()` for stripes as well. Thanks for that. Unfortunately, the solution doesn't work for me, since group of columns are faceted by `facet_wrap( ..., scale= "free_x" )`. Nevermind, the question was not detailed enough, so I accept your answer.

Comment: @Beasterfield How do you change the colour of the point, to something else than black?

Answer (score 6):

As @joran suggested in the comments, you can pass a subset of the data to a particular layer.

Using your example data

```
g <- ggplot( molten ) +
  geom_raster( aes( x = Var1, y = Var2, fill = value )  ) + 
  scale_fill_gradient2( low = "blue", high = "red", na.value="black", name = "" ) +
  geom_point(data = molten[molten$na,], aes( x = Var1, y = Var2, size= as.numeric(na) ) )


g
```

[image]

If you wanted the legend to say something about what the dots signify

```
 g <- ggplot( molten ) +
  geom_raster( aes( x = Var1, y = Var2, fill = value )  ) + 
  scale_fill_gradient2( low = "blue", high = "red", na.value="black", name = "" ) +
  geom_point(data = molten[molten$na,], aes( x = Var1, y = Var2, colour = 'black' )) +
  scale_colour_manual(name = 'Ooh look', values = 'black', labels = 'Something cool')
```

[image]

Comment: Thumbs up for the "Ooh look" example.

Comment: @mnel How do you change the colour of the point, to something else than black?