# Highlight tiles with ggplot2 geom_tile() + geom_point()

Tags: r, statistics, ggplot2

I have the following plot that looks like:

[image]

I'm trying to add points in another layer using according to the following code found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13258454/marking-specific-tiles-in-geom-tile-geom-raster)

My data frame i'm importing looks like this:

```
residue_id  residue_num per_ddg pg9_seq_bool
A   96  0.00437094862845686 FALSE
A   97  -0.0026333752377897 FALSE
A   98  -0.00453070737795937    FALSE
A   99  -0.0130564560942629 TRUE
A   100 -0.00578979380922636    FALSE
A   101 -0.0128130535970934 FALSE
A   102 -0.0264740211311766 FALSE
A   103 -0.183036342874782  FALSE
A   104 -0.00550669729238368    FALSE
```

and uses the following code to generate the plot:

```
library(ggplot2)
input_ddg <-read.table('per_residue_average.txt',header=T,sep="\t",stringsAsFactors=TRUE)
input_ddg$pg9_seq_bool[input_ddg$pg9_seq == "TRUE"] <- T
input_ddg$pg9_seq_bool[input_ddg$pg9_seq == "FALSE"] <- F


pdf("output.pdf")                                                                                                                                                      
ggplot(input_ddg, aes(residue_id,residue_num,fill=per_ddg) ) +                            
  theme_bw() +                                                                
  geom_tile() +                  
  geom_point(data=input_ddg,aes(size=ifelse(pg9_seq_bool, "dot", "no_dot"))) +
  scale_size_manual(values=c(dot=6,no_dot=NA))+                                                                 
  scale_fill_gradient2(low="blue", mid="white",high="red", midpoint=-.25, na.value="black") +     
  ylab( "Residue Number" ) +                                                  
  xlab( "Mutation Identity")    +     
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=96:125,expand=c(0,0))+
  scale_x_discrete(expand=c(0,0))+
  labs(fill=expression(Delta*Delta*"G(REU)")) +
  ggtitle(expression("Average"~Delta*Delta*"G for Mutations by CDR3 Position")) +
  theme(  panel.background=element_rect(fill="black"), panel.grid.minor=element_blank(), panel.grid.major=element_blank())
dev.off()
```

I'm getting an error:

```
Error in grid.Call.graphics(L_setviewport, pvp, TRUE) : 
Non-finite location and/or size for viewport
Calls: print ... lapply -> FUN -> push.vp.viewport -> grid.Call.graphics
In addition: Warning message:
Removed 461 rows containing missing values (geom_point). 
Execution halted
```

I have a feeling its to due with my parsing of the TRUE and FALSE with ifelse, but I followed the post exactly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, you don't need to replace TRUE and FALSE values with T and F in your data fram `input_ddg`. Next, column `pg9_seq_bool` can be used directly in `aes()` of `geom_point()`. This will produce two types of points according to TRUE/FALSE values. Then with `scale_size_manual()` set size 0 for FALSE and 6 for TRUE. If this point size shouldn't appear in legend then add argument `guide="none"` in `scale_size_maual()`.

```
ggplot(input_ddg, aes(residue_id,residue_num,fill=per_ddg) ) +                            
  theme_bw() +                                                                
  geom_tile() +                  
  geom_point(aes(size=pg9_seq_bool)) +
  scale_size_manual(values=c(0,6),guide="none")
```

[image]

Comment: Yes sorry, I had to get to work today to make sure it did indeed work :)