# Highlight groups of tiles defined by clusters using ggplot2 geom_tile()

Tags: r, ggplot2, visualization

I using ggplot2 to examine some clustering for a dataset. It would be great if I was able to highlight the groups of nodes that belong to the same cluster by drawing a box around them or something. Below you'll find some sample code that reproduces what I'm trying to do but the real data is, as always, way more messy. :)

I've hunted around and came across this solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16351518/highlight-tiles-with-ggplot2-geom-tile-geom-point) to a slightly different question. Ideally, in my case, the border would only be drawn around the outside of the clusters.

```
set.seed(1916)
# what cluster do each user belong to?
cl_df = tibble(user = 1:100, cl = rep(1:3, c(20,30,50)))

df_example = 
  # create the grid
  expand.grid(user_1 = 1:100, user_2 = 1:100) %>% as_tibble %>%
  mutate(cl_1 = plyr::mapvalues(user_1, cl_df$user, cl_df$cl), 
         cl_2 = plyr::mapvalues(user_2, cl_df$user, cl_df$cl),
         same_cl = cl_1 == cl_2, 
         value = ifelse(same_cl, rnorm(sum(same_cl),1,1), rnorm(sum(!same_cl),2,1)))

df_example %>%
  ggplot(data = ., aes(x = reorder(user_1, cl_1),
                     y = reorder(user_2, cl_2), 
                     fill = value)) +
  geom_tile() + 
  scale_fill_gradientn(colours = terrain.colors(10)) +
  xlab('') + 
  ylab('') + 
  theme(axis.text.x=element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.x=element_blank(),
        axis.text.y=element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.y=element_blank())
```

In the above case there are three clusters along the diagonal that I would like to highlight with a box around each.

Thanks in advance (I'm getting to the stage where I might just us MS paint!)

Comment: You might try `ggforce::geom_mark_ellipse` (https://www.data-imaginist.com/2019/the-ggforce-awakens-again/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `geom_mark_*` functions from `ggforce` are helpful for this task. In this case, we can specify that we want one for each `cl_1` group, and we only want to highlight the data with `same_cl`.

```
 ...
 ggforce::geom_mark_rect(aes(group = cl_1, filter = same_cl), 
                         expand = 0, radius = 0)
```

[image]

Comment: One thing I don't love about my approach is that the rectangle is drawn around the underlying points, but `geom_tile` extends farther. It's straightforward to manually fiddle with `expand` but I haven't figured out a good automatic way to get the alignment perfect.

Comment: Thanks! I add a fudge factor to make it pretty! This is really great because I'm trying to automatically generate these and the cluster side can change between dataset. Awesome; thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
graphics.off()
ggplot(data = df_example, aes(x = reorder(user_1, cl_1),
                 y = reorder(user_2, cl_2), 
                 fill = value)) +
    geom_tile() + 
    scale_fill_gradientn(colours = terrain.colors(10)) +
    xlab('') + 
    ylab('') + 
    theme(axis.text.x=element_blank(),
          axis.ticks.x=element_blank(),
          axis.text.y=element_blank(),
          axis.ticks.y=element_blank()) + 
geom_rect(mapping = aes(xmin = 1, xmax = 20, ymin = 1, ymax = 20),
          fill = NA, col = "black")  + 
geom_rect(mapping = aes(xmin = 20, xmax = 50, ymin = 20, ymax = 50),
          fill = NA, col = "black") +
geom_rect(mapping = aes(xmin = 50, xmax = 100, ymin = 50, ymax = 100),
          fill = NA, col = "black")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I was actually messing around with this geom this morning but needed it to be a little more automated but geom_rect is a handy one to be aware of!

Comment: It's worth noting that adjusting `xmin`, `xmax` etc. by 0.5 will make the rectangle borders align perfectly with the inter-tile spacing: `aes(xmin = 19.5, xmax = 50.5, ymin = 19.5, ymax = 50.5)`.