# Mark tiles in logarithmic geom_raster

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have seen [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13258454/marking-specific-tiles-in-geom-tile-geom-raster), but I'm struggling to translate that to a logarithmic raster.

For example:

```
library(tidyverse)
a <- tibble(x = rep(10^seq(-2, 2), 5), 
            y = rep(10^seq(-2, 2), each = 5),
            z = runif(25))

a %>%
  ggplot(aes(x, y)) +
  geom_raster(aes(fill = z)) +
  scale_x_log10() +
  scale_y_log10()
```

How do I now get for example a box around the row with `y = 0.1`? Or a box around just one tile?

I know that the half-point between two points on a logarithmic scale is calculated by the geometric mean.

**Update:**

For the example above, the solution seems to work but not if `x` and `y` look a little different, e.g.:

```
n_x <- 10^seq(log10(6), log10(24*365), by = 0.1)/365
n_y <- 10^seq(-1, 3, by = 0.1)

a <- tibble(x = rep(n_x, length(n_y)), 
            y = rep(n_y, each = length(n_x)),
            z = runif(length(n_x)*length(n_y)))

h <- a$y[which.min(abs(a$y - 1.14*24))]

h.tb <- a %>%
  dplyr::filter(y == h)

a %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_raster(aes(fill = z)) +
  scale_x_log10() +
  scale_y_log10(breaks = c(1, h, 100), labels = c('1', 'h', '100')) +
  geom_tile(data = h.tb, fill = NA, colour = "black", size = 2)
```

Interestingly, `h.tb` contains the correct data.

Comment: I don't have a full answer figured out, but try filtering your data for a second `geom_raster` layer, such as `data = . %>% filter(y == 0.1)`. You could then set a transparent fill and border color, but that puts borders around each of the tiles in that row. You could filter easily enough for just one tile as well, but I'm not sure about making the whole row one tile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming for example that you want to mark tiles in the y = 0.1 row, for x < 10, adding `geom_tile()` like the following could work:

```
p1 <- a %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_raster(aes(fill = z)) +
  scale_x_log10() +
  scale_y_log10() +
  geom_tile(data = . %>% filter(y == 0.1 & x < 10), # filter dataset for desired tiles
            fill = NA,                              # make tiles transparent
            colour = "black", size = 2)             # aesthetic choices

p1
```

[image: plot]

If you want the tiles to form a single rectangle, I can't think of an equally straightforward method, but it can be done.

```
# continuing from above, using the geom_tile layer from p1 to 
# obtain the correct tile dimensions, then transform all measures
# back to the non-log form
p1.data <- layer_data(p1, 2) %>%
  summarise(xmin = min(xmin), xmax = max(xmax),
            ymin = min(ymin), ymax = max(ymax)) %>%
  mutate_all(function(x) 10^x)

> p1.data
         xmin     xmax       ymin      ymax
1 0.003162278 3.162278 0.03162278 0.3162278

# replace the geom_tile() layer earlier with geom_rect() & the new data
a %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_raster(aes(fill = z)) +
  scale_x_log10() +
  scale_y_log10() +
  geom_rect(data = p1.data,
            aes(xmin = xmin, xmax = xmax,
                ymin = ymin, ymax = ymax),
            inherit.aes = FALSE, fill = NA, 
            colour = "black", size = 2)
```

[image: plot2]

Comment: Thanks. Being able to use `%>%` is something I didn't know was possible within a ggplot command.

Comment: This, works great in my dummy example. But curiously not with my real data. I've updated the post accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

For the updated example, one just needs to add `height = 0.1` to `geom_tile` where the value of `height` needs to fit the `by` value in `n_y`.

```
n_x <- 10^seq(log10(6), log10(24*365), by = 0.1)/365
step_y <- 0.1
n_y <- 10^seq(-1, 3, by = step_y)

a <- tibble(x = rep(n_x, length(n_y)), 
            y = rep(n_y, each = length(n_x)),
            z = runif(length(n_x)*length(n_y)))

h <- a$y[which.min(abs(a$y - 1.14*24))]

h.tb <- a %>%
  dplyr::filter(y == h)

a %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_raster(aes(fill = z)) +
  scale_x_log10() +
  scale_y_log10(breaks = c(1, h, 100), labels = c('1', 'h', '100')) +
  geom_tile(data = h.tb, fill = NA, colour = "black", size = 2, height = step_y)
```