# How to overlay geom_tile heatmap with second indicator geom_tile layer?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to highlight a single tile in a heatmap with

```
ggplot(faithfuld, aes(waiting, eruptions)) +
    geom_raster(aes(fill = density)) +
    geom_tile(data = faithfuld[50, ],  fill = "red")
```

However, the result is not highlighting the (here randomly selected) tile, but rather adds some more arbitray tile.

[image]

Why is that, and how would I add my second `geom_tile` layer with correct tile dimensions?

Comment: what is the result of adding a second geom_raster?

Comment: The way I would do this is to create a dummy variable for the area you want in red in your original dataframe and passing it to your  geom_tile as a fill aes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `geom_tile` in your image highlights the exact tile you want (it takes the given data points and sets them as the centre of the tile), but it's hard to see this because the tile it creates is very long. If you play with `width` and `height` settings, you can get something more reasonable.

```
ggplot(faithfuld, aes(waiting, eruptions)) +
  geom_raster(aes(fill = density)) +
  geom_tile(data = faithfuld[50, ],  width = 1, height = 0.1, fill = "red")
```

[image: example]

EDIT:

How to get the exact height and width of `geom_raster` and use it with `geom_tile` (the default values are 1 for both):

```
p <- ggplot(faithfuld, aes(waiting, eruptions)) +
  geom_raster(aes(fill = density))

tmp <- ggplot_build(p)$data[[1]][2,]  # get the first data point from geom_raster
width <- tmp$xmax - tmp$xmin  # calculate the width of the rectangle
height <- tmp$ymax - tmp$ymin  # calculate the height of the rectangle
p <- p +
  geom_tile(data = faithfuld[50, ],  width = width, height = height, fill = "red")
```

[image: example 2]

There are also other solutions, like this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13258454/marking-specific-tiles-in-geom-tile-geom-raster?rq=1) where you make the variables categorical.

Comment: Not it's not the tile I want. It should be a single tile with respect to the resolution of the heatmap, but it's much bigger. I don't think that tweaking the width and height solves the problem. Rather, ggplot should be instructed to respect tile-dimensions at the second layer. But I don't know how to do so, that's why I have asked the question.

Comment: I've edited my answer to show you how you can get the exact values for the `width` and `height`.

Comment: Thanks, Arienrhod for your help. Your second solution is what I was looking for. I still wonder why ggplot gets it wrong in the first place, isn't the second layer somehow inheriting the coordinate system of the first layer?

Comment: If you check the source code of `geom_tile`, you can see that the line that sets the `height` and the `width` does so in 3 different ways: 1) it uses `height` and `width` columns from your data (if they exist), 2) it uses the`height` or `width` arguments provided with the function call, 3) if two first options are not used, it checks the `resolution` of the data (defined as the smallest non-zero distance between adjacent values). However, if you only have one unique value (like in your `faithfuld[50, ]` case), resolution is 1 and therefore your `width` and `height`.